# Selenium - Raises httplib.BadStatusLine

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS with Selenium, I want to do several searches on stackoverflow. This code worked fine with my local pc, when I changed it to a server with less RAM it raises the httplib.BadStatusLine error. 
This sounds either like a problem with the installs or with exceeding system specs, can someone clarify how to solve this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

start = time.time()
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
array = ["Python", "Javascript", "Golang", "C++", "C", "CSS", "XML", "Json", "Ruby", "Django",
     "Rails", "Java", "OpenCV", "GameMaker", "iOS", "Android", "React", "AngularJS", "React Native"]
for i in array:
    driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
    sbtn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search"]/input')
    sbtn.send_keys(i)
    sbtn.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    driver.save_screenshot('Photos/screen' + i + '.png') # save a screenshot to disk
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.save_screenshot('Photos/screen' + i + '.png') # save a screenshot to disk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 798, in get_screenshot_as_file
    png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 817, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 827, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 408, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 478, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the error because you ran out of memory on the server, so you'll need to increase the amount of memory. I'll assume that you have more memory on your local computer, hence, the reason why it runs as expected. Unfortunately, PhantomJS + Selenium are memory intensive.